# Dask ram issues

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I am facing problems when using Dask dataframe to process a large dataset. Specifically, the issue is that with the current version of the code I run out of memory even in a Google virtual machine with 100 GB RAM.

The sample code below represents a snippet of what I am trying to achieve and replicates the main error: Without setting up the client (Dask distrubted), the program is killed by the OS in my local machine when running the load parquet function. I believe this is because the machine runs out of RAM. When running the same program with the client, my system crashes and I can monitor the processing in port 8787.

I understand that merging in Dask requires shuffling especially with an unindexed column, but so does setting the index. However, I am still not quite sure what causes the machine to run out of RAM.

I would appreciate input as to where I am doing something wrong and how to fix it/set it up in a better and more Dask-specific way.

Different scenarios:

1. first saving and loading without the client:

   1. create both parquet files with

      ```py
       create_parquet('parquet_test', False)
       create_parquet('parquet_testII', False)
      ```
   2. load parquet with `load('parquet_test', 'parquet_testII', False)`.
      This runs out of memory on the second step.
2. second scenario with client:

   1. comment out the create_parquet functions(should load already existing data created without client)
      load parquet with `load('parquet_test', 'parquet_testII', True, client)`. This should run out of memory.
   2. leave the create_parquet functions like so:

      ```py
      create_parquet('parquet_test', True, client)
      create_parquet('parquet_testII', False, None)
      ```

      should give this error:
      `concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError`

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
from random import random, choice, uniform
import numpy as np
import string
import gc


def create_parquet(*args) -> None:
    if args[1]:
        args[2]()
    n = 20000000
    d = { ''.join(choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(7)) : np.random.random_sample(n) * 100 for i in range(100) }
    partition_col = np.random.randint(101, size=n)
    d['partition_col'] = partition_col
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    print('about to save')
    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=50)
    ddf.to_parquet(args[0], engine="fastparquet")

def load(*args) -> None:
    name_1 = args[0]
    name_2 = args[1]
    if args[2]:
        args[3]()
    # load merge and save
    ddf_1 = dd.read_parquet(name_1)
    ddf_2 = dd.read_parquet(name_2)
    ddf_1.set_index("partition_col")
    ddf_2.set_index("partition_col")
    merged = ddf_1.merge(ddf_2, left_on=["partition_col"],
                                right_on = ["partition_col"], how="right")
    print('merging complete', merged)

    merged.to_parquet('merged', engine="fastparquet")

def create_client():
    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=4, 
                        threads_per_worker=1,
                        memory_limit='8GB')
    client = Client(cluster)
    client = Client(cluster)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create parquet
    client = create_client
    create_parquet('parquet_test', False, None)
    create_parquet('parquet_testII', False, None)
    # load
    load('parquet_test', 'parquet_testII', False)
```

Comment: There is quite. a lot here. Do you think you can reduce the number of components to try to isolate the problem?

Comment: Yes, when I have the data already in place, and run the load command without the setting index, it fails at the merging part of the code. If I take out the merging part and save one of the dfs, it does go through.